# $\mathbb Z_m$ where every unit is an involution

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

What are all $m \in \mathbb N_{\geq 2}$ such that $\forall a \in (\mathbb Z_m^*): a^2 \equiv_m 1$? Hints would be nice :)

This is not homework and question 2.24 in "Introduction to Algebra" from J. Cameron.

Comment: Do you have a classification of unit groups? This condition can equivalently be stated as $U(m)=({\bf Z}/m{\bf Z})^\times\cong C_2\oplus C_2\oplus\cdots$ (i.e. the group of units has exponent two) - why?

Comment: What does $\mathbb{Z}_m^{*}$ mean ?

Comment: The units of $\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z$ where the units $a$ are the elements with $gcd(a,m) = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the chinese remainder theorem, we can restrict ourselves to the case where $m$ is a prime power. If $m$ is odd, we must have $2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod m$, hence $m = 3$. If $m = 2^k$, we must have $3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod m$, hence $m|8$, i.e. $m \in \{2,4,8\}$. So the only possibilities where $m$ is a prime power are $m=2,3,4,8$, an indeed these $m$ all satisfy $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod m$ for all $a \in (\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^*$.
By the chinese remainder theorem, the non-prime-power solutions are $3\cdot 2, 3\cdot 4$ and $3\cdot 8.$

Summarizing, $$a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod m \;\forall a \in (\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^* \Leftrightarrow m= 2,3,4,6,8,12,24.$$

Comment: Ok that looks quite convincing but I have to verify it for myself :D Why do you assume that $m  = 2^k$ after you checked what happens for $m$ is odd ?

Comment: Write $m = p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$ as a product of prime powers. Then, by the CRT, $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^* \cong (\mathbb Z/p_1^{e_1}\mathbb Z)^* \times \ldots \times (\mathbb Z/p_r^{e_r}\mathbb Z)^*$. That implies $a^2 = 1 \; \forall a \in (\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^* \Leftrightarrow a^2 = 1 \; \forall a \in (\mathbb Z/p_i^{e_i}\mathbb Z)^*, i=1,\ldots,r$. That's why we only need to consider the case where $m$ is a prime power, and every prime power is either odd or $2^k$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that it must be

$$(\Bbb Z_m)^*\cong \prod_{j=1}^k C_2\;\;,\;\;C_2=\,\text{cyclic group of order}\,\,2$$

for some $\,k\in\Bbb N\Longrightarrow\,\phi(m)=2^k\,$ for some natural $\,k\,$ , so the only options seem to be $\,m=2,\,3,\,4,\,6,\,8\,12,\,24$ according to the [structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Structure) of the group of units modulo $\,m\,$

Comment: I dont know why the isomorphism holds and I have tested that 12 and 24 work, too.

Comment: True, I missed those two.

Comment: I favorited this +1